# sqlite How to get whole month data from table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to get data of whole month,which date I pass like if I give 01/12/2015
then i need to get all data of month  date month.

Comment: What code do you have currently?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please show some code snippets and the SO community will help you identify the problem and solving it much faster.

Comment: have you tried using SELECT * FROM `table name` WHERE strftime('%m', `date column`) = '04'    // where 04 is april, i.e. you can retrieve all data for a particular month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you can try the sqlite date and time functions--
[SQLITE date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

According to this you can pass time and date parameters can be passed as arguments, along with the `**strftime**` it proves to be a very powerful tool. Some specifiers are--

```
%d      day of month: 00
%f      fractional seconds: SS.SSS
%H      hour: 00-24
%m      month: 01-12 where, Jan=01, Feb=02, ... ... ... December==12.
%M      minute: 00-59
%S      seconds: 00-59
%w      day of week 0-6 with Sunday==0, Monday==1, ... ... Saturday==6.
%Y      year: 0000-9999
```

For example if you want to do a select * for the month of april, it will be like,

```
SELECT * FROM `table name` WHERE strftime('%m', `date column`) = '04'
```

Comment: thanks for answer i want to put query in content provider projection    String date = "12 2015";
   c = new CursorLoader(
    this,
    HollaContractClass.Hollas.TRIP_HISTORY_URI,
    PROJECTION,
    HollaContractClass.Hollas.HollaTripHistoryColumns.STATUS
      + " = ? AND "
      + " strftime( %m %Y ,"+ HollaContractClass.Hollas.HollaTripHistoryColumns.START_DATE+") =?",
    new String[] { "finished",date},
    HollaContractClass.Hollas.HollaTripHistoryColumns.START_DATE
      + " asc"); but application crash

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY strftime('%m', '2015-12-01');
```

This might be helpful to you.

Comment: you have not mention column name so how will it work

Comment: At the place of dte you can just pass the col name such as strftime('%m', COL_NAME);